# Как получить хэш андроид приложения?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Разбираюсь с SMS Retriever API(https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview).
В требованиях к смс сообщению с одноразовым кодом, среди прочего, описано требование, чтобы смс приходило с подписью (подписью является хэш приложения, минимум из 11 символов). В этой же статье написано, что не рекомендуется получать хэш из приложения.
Главный вопрос: как можно получить хэш приложения, и может ли он меняться в процессе разных доработок приложения в будущем, или он статический?
Пока разбирался с АПИ нашел код который выдаёт хэш, но никак не выходит найти как можно получить такой хэш не через код в приложении.
Код который выдаёт нужный хэш:

```
private static final String TAG = "AppSignatureHelper";
private static final String HASH_TYPE = "SHA-256";
public static final int NUM_HASHED_BYTES = 9;
public static final int NUM_BASE64_CHAR = 11;

public AppSignatureHelper(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public ArrayList<String> getAppSignatures() {
    ArrayList<String> appCodes = new ArrayList<>();


    try {
        // Get all package signatures for the current package
        String packageName = getPackageName();
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        Signature[] signatures = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName,
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;
        // For each signature create a compatible hash
        for (Signature signature : signatures) {
            String hash = hash(packageName, signature.toCharsString());
            if (hash != null) {
                appCodes.add(String.format("%s", hash));
            }
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to find package to obtain hash.", e);
    }
    return appCodes;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private static String hash(String packageName, String signature) {
    String appInfo = packageName + " " + signature;
    try {
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(HASH_TYPE);
        messageDigest.update(appInfo.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] hashSignature = messageDigest.digest();

        // truncated into NUM_HASHED_BYTES
        hashSignature = Arrays.copyOfRange(hashSignature, 0, NUM_HASHED_BYTES);
        // encode into Base64
        String base64Hash = Base64.encodeToString(hashSignature, Base64.NO_PADDING | Base64.NO_WRAP);
        base64Hash = base64Hash.substring(0, NUM_BASE64_CHAR);

        Log.e(TAG, String.format("pkg: %s -- hash: %s", packageName, base64Hash));
        return base64Hash;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "hash:NoSuchAlgorithm", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Вам нужен хэш SHA-256?

Comment: Если я всё правильно понимаю то да

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что достаточно будет сгенерировать хэш с помощью любого онлайн генератора ([например](https://hash.online-convert.com/ru/sha256-generator)).

Хэш должен меняться в процессе доработок приложения (файл apk будет отличаться содержимым и хэш тоже будет разный).

Comment: Расскажите, пожалуйста, подробнее как пользоваться сервисом, который приведен как пример? Что необходимо загружать на сайте?

Comment: Необходимо выбрать отладочный файл apk, собранный AndroidStudio (у меня он лежит в папке `\app\build\outputs\apk\debug` как `app-debug.apk`) или подписанный своей подписью (насколько помню, местоположение указывается при сборке).

Comment: Попробовал сделать, но хэш не подходит.

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://medium.com/android-dev-hacks/autofill-otp-verification-with-latest-sms-retriever-api-73c788636783).

Comment: Да, спасибо. Видел эту статью, тут в 5-м шаге рассказывается про два варианта получения этого хэша, через код который я скинул в вопросе и через cmd, но описывается только вариант с дополнительным классом, который после получения хэш-кода нужно удалить. А вот как можно получить этот хэш через командную строку? я этого так и не смог найти

Comment: Может быть [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51365778/how-to-generate-11-char-hash-key-for-sms-retriever-with-google-app-signing) поможет сгенерировать хэш через командную строку?

Comment: Спасибо, попробую